# VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT vs VIDIOC_TRY_FMT

Tags: webrtc, v4l2

I experience some unexpected behavior from my camera. Using `VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT` for `V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE` I receive two supported formats: **MJPG** and **YUYV**. But when I try (actually WebRTC `DeviceInfoLinux::FillCapabilities()` tries for me) to list supported formats with `VIDIOC_TRY_FMT`, it happily reports much more:

```
supported   MJPG 640x480x30
supported   MJPG 1280x720x15
supported   I420 640x480x30
supported   I420 1280x720x15
supported   YUY2 160x120x30
supported   YUY2 320x240x30
supported   YUY2 640x480x30
supported   YUY2 1280x720x15
supported   UYVY 640x480x30
supported   UYVY 1280x720x15
```

Are some of these formats emulated by the video driver?

Answer (score 0):

Digging deeper into the answer produced by `VIDIOC_TRY_FMT` reveals an interesting fact that is completely ignored by **DeviceInfoLinux**: the answer `pixformat` is not always equal to the query `pixformat` (also, answer width and height are not equal to query width and height). Actually, only MJPG and YUYV appear as results, so IMHO this is a bug of WebRTC to show these formats as supported: they [check that the sizes are equal](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/stable/webrtc/+/master/modules/video_capture/linux/device_info_linux.cc#284), but not the `pixformat`.